# Using custom methods in scope/refactoring custom methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am making a Instagram-like clone where users upload pics that get voted on.

How can I refactor this code?
How can I default scope it by decreasing percent?

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
    has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
    has_many :votes, :dependent => :destroy

    def vote_count
        return self.votes.count
    end

    def up_votes
        return self.votes.where('up like ?', true).count.to_f
    end

    def down_votes
        return self.votes.where('up like ?', false).count.to_f
    end

    def percent
        return self.up_votes/self.vote_count
    end

end
```

FYI my Vote model just tracks the picture and user id and has up:boolean, :default => false

This all seems less concise than it could be, how would you write this better?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
    has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
    has_many :votes, :dependent => :destroy

    def vote_count
        return self.votes.count
    end

    def votes_status(status)
        return self.votes.where('up like ?', status).count.to_f
    end

    def percent
        return self.votes_status(true)/self.vote_count
    end

end
```

Comment: You can move these methods on scope like this
scope :votes_status, lambda {|status=false|
    self.votes.where('up like ?', status).count.to_f
}